# CSS grid area pushing other areas out of position based on content

Tags: html, css

So I seem to have this problem everytime  I start a new project with CSS grid and that is  - 1 grid area pushing another grid area smaller based on content size.

I've done it in the past but don't remember how I pulled it off. Anyone can assist me with this?

```css
body {
  background-color: #292929;
  /*#333333 is a lighter charcoal color go to https://encycolorpedia.com/333333 to play around with shades*/
  font-family: Acme;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Main Grid Container*/

#main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'calendar calendar displaylist displaylist'
}


/*Child of Main Grid Container*/

#calendarFavs {
  grid-area: calendar;
}

#displayedList {
  grid-area: displaylist;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <div id='main-grid'>
    <!--Calendar grid containers and its children -->
    <div id='calendarFavs'>
      <h1>Calendar</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- End of calendar grid containers and its children -->

    <div id='displayedList'>
      <h1>List</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your code doesn't replicate what you are saying, could you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add:

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: The "not an answer" flag doesn't mean *incorrect* answer, @kukkuz. It means "not an attempt to answer the question". If an answer is wrong, you should downvote it, not flag it. See [the Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). Moderators don't judge technical accuracy.